# Ideals generated by two elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

The question is this:

> Let $f:\mathbb C[x,y]\rightarrow\mathbb C[t]$ be the homomorphism that sends $x\mapsto t+1$ and $y\mapsto t^3-1.$ Determine the kernel $K$ of $f$, and prove that every ideal $I$ of $\mathbb C[x,y]$ that contains $K$ can be generated by two elements.

Solution:

I have shown that $((x-1)^3-y-1)=K.$ However, I am having trouble showing the second part. Any hints??

Comment: I assume $C$ is supposed to be the complex numbers, or at least a field?  In that case, consider that $C[t]$ is a PID, and that as $f$ is surjective, it induces an isomorphism $C[x,y]/K \to C[t]$.

Comment: Yes $C$ is the complex field. So does this mean then, that if $I$ is an ideal in $C[x,y]$, then $I$ will also be an ideal in $C[x,y]/K$ and since this is isomorphic to $C[t]$ and all ideals are principal here, and can be generated by more than one element, then I is generated by more than one??

Answer (score 3):

We know that $\mathbb C[x,y]/K \cong \mathbb C[t]$, and that $\mathbb C[t]$ is a PID, being the ring of polynomials in one variable over a field. Thus, $\mathbb C[x,y]/K$ is also a PID.  Therefore, if $I$ is any ideal containing $K$, we know that $I/K$ is principal in $\mathbb C[x,y]/K$, so it can be written $(\bar{z})$ where $\bar{z}$ is the coset of some element $z \in \mathbb C[x,y]$.  It remains to check that $z$ and $(x-1)^3-y-1$ generate $I$.  This would show that $I$ is generated by at most two elements, which is what the problem asks.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!